# using jquery, handlebars with simple inline template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebars template  in my page with Jquery. Its a simple page with static data, template in script tag.  Here is my html, the problem is Jquery does not load my script tag which contains my template,

> var source=$('#tasks-template').html();

source is undefined, why is this undefined?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js" />
  <script id="tasks-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
      {{#tasks}}
      <li>
        <span>{{name}}</span>  <span>{{count}}</span> 
      </li>
      {{/tasks}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script>
    function replaceContent() {
      var tasks = [{
        name: 'A',
        count: 9
      }, {
        name: 'B',
        count: 10
      }]
      console.log(tasks);
      var source = $('#tasks-template').html();
      console.log("template src  " + source)
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      $('#content-placeholder').html(template(tasks));
    }
    replaceContent();
  </script>

</head>


<body>
  <div id="content-placeholder">
    some content
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

link

> http://plnkr.co/edit/WdHIzaCLAUduUYJWsU2m?p=preview

I am trying to figure how to load a template from inline script

here is the html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js" />

</head>

<body>
<script id="templateA" type="text/template">
 <ul>
            {{#tasks}}
            <li>                
                    <span>{{name}}</span>  <span>{{count}}</span>  
            </li>
            {{/tasks}}
        </ul>   
</script>

<script id="templateB" type="text/template">
        <ul>
            {{#tasks}}
            <li>                
                    <span>{{name}}</span>  <span>{{count}}</span>  
            </li>
            {{/tasks}}
        </ul>   

</script>
<script>
  alert($('#templateA').html());
  alert($('#templateB').html());
</script>
    <div id="content-placeholder">
        some content
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

link

> http://plnkr.co/edit/aCWg3

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script id="templateA" type="text/template">
    <ul>
      {{#tasks}}
      <li>
        <span>{{name}}</span>  <span>{{count}}</span> 
      </li>
      {{/tasks}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script id="templateB" type="text/template">
    <ul>
      {{#tasks}}
      <li>
        <span>{{name}}</span>  <span>{{count}}</span> 
      </li>
      {{/tasks}}
    </ul>

  </script>
  <script>
    alert($('#templateA').html());
    alert($('#templateB').html());
  </script>
  <div id="content-placeholder">
    some content
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

xN3Z5xei8S5EJqu?p=preview

templateA results in undefined but templateB prints out,  why templateA is undefined and templateB is not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coloring of your syntax should give you the clue:

`script` tags need to be closed with a `</script>` and cannot use `<script />`:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js" />
...
            {{/tasks}}
        </ul>   
</script>     <-- This closes the above script that loads handlebars -->
```

Change:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js" />
```

to (add a closing tag):

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js"></script>
```